# AWS RDS Postgresql API with lambdas very slow right after creation

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, crud

I created a simple CRUD API following some tutorials online. I used serverless to create the API endpoints with lambdas functions and a Postgresql on RDS.

The lambdas and the database are on eu-west-3. I then have a react and a react native app that are simply using fetch to send or get data to and from the database calling the lambdas. While it seems extremely simple I have huge performance issues. Just to save a JSON object of a few key/value pairs is taking several seconds and to get the data from the table (with 10 rows) is more than 5 seconds as well.

I am using the free tier so I know the server ain't the most powerful (db.t2.micro) but right now I am just asking the most basic requests and I am the only one using it. Any idea where the bottleneck could be ? Did I forget someting basic (I am new to Postgresql so don't have a clear vision about indexes) to configure to avoid this speed ?

I tried to increase the memory of the lambdas to 1024 mb but didnt change anything so I guess they are not the bottleneck. I am based in central Europe so Paris (eu-west-3) ain't next door but ain't very far either.

I have two tables, both are slow. One is 25 columns and the other one 5 columns. Data are simple with a primary key named ID which is a text field. Other fields are either text, integer or boolean.

Very stuck here so hoping for your help.

Comment: I doubt this is a problem with the database itself. More likely the lambdas are taking some time to spin up. Try checking the logs to see what part of the request actually takes that long.

Comment: Right you were, problem was in my lambda. Had to add :   context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false
otherwise the lambda was not triggering the callback directly. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My lambda function was not triggering the callback directly because the following line was missing :

```
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false
```

Therefor it was always waiting for a timeout to send the response.

See documentation : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-context.html